# Gradle file changed Mistakenly android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When Building the project an option came up in android studio to load in a different encoding. I click on it and now My build.gradle file for project, app and the manifest file looks like this. And the app is not compiling

build.gradle(Project)

```
Êþº¾   2  z { | } ~ Namer InnerClasses   TASK_NAME 
Ljava/lang/String; 
ConstantValue  TASK_DESCRIPTION  
TASK_GROUP   TASK_TYPE  TASK_DEPENDS_ON 0 TASK_OVERWRITE 
 TASK_ACTION  TASK_CONSTRUCTOR_ARGS  
RuntimeVisibleAnnotations Lorg/gradle/api/Incubating; getName 
()Ljava/lang/String; Lorg/gradle/api/tasks/Internal; 
getProject ()Lorg/gradle/api/Project; 
getActions ()Ljava/util/List;    Signature 
C()Ljava/util/List<Lorg/gradle/api/Action<-Lorg/gradle/api/Task;>;>; 
setActions (Ljava/util/List;)V 
D(Ljava/util/List<Lorg/gradle/api/Action<-Lorg/gradle/api/Task;>;>;)V 
getTaskDependencies '()Lorg/gradle/api/t
```

build.gradle (app):

```
Êþº¾   2  
  apply (Ljava/lang/Object;)V    Signature (TT;)V 
(<T:Ljava/lang/Object;>Ljava/lang/Object; 
SourceFile Plugin.java org/gradle/api/Plugin java/lang/Object
```

Android Manifest file:

```
����   2   
 execute (Ljava/lang/Object;)V     Signature (TT;)V 
(<T:Ljava/lang/Object;>Ljava/lang/Object; 
SourceFile Action.java RuntimeVisibleAnnotations 
$Lorg/gradle/api/HasImplicitReceiver; org/gradle/api/Action 
java/lang/Object
```

I have no idea what happened? This is a project I'm working on for very long time. Please tell me how to solve this.

Comment: Try to clear cache and rebuild your project

Comment: @AshwinNirmale I've tried that already not working

Comment: @AshwinNirmale I've tried that already not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First **Close your Android Studio**.

Go to your **C:** Drive. Follow Path: **C://Users/yourUserName/.AndroidStudio3.4**

There is .AndroidStudio Folder. **Delete** that folder. Then start studio again. Setup things studio asked, and you will get your project back with proper code.

Comment: @Tintin have you tried this?? This will Help you for sure

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I re-import the android project (Manifest error solved), then manually copied the build.gradle file of project level from another project bcoz almost every build.gradle file is almost same.

Comment: you need  to copy your code by manually, if you tried my suggestion, then there no need to do anything, not any single copy-paste